# Docker compose: meaning of {} in volume definition

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-volume

What is the meaning of `{}` in volume definition?

For example

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  dataelasticsearch: {}

services:   
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
    volumes:
      - ./dataelasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Comment: Wouldn't it mean an empty set?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado A set in YAML looks like `!!set {}`, this is an empty mapping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just an empty mapping. It just means that no extra options were given to the named volume.

From the tests I have done, this is no different from leaving it blank like:

```
volumes:
   dataelasticsearch:
```

The docker-compose [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volume-configuration-reference) do not give any more insights into this.

One more thing: you are defining a named volume at the top but then you are binding a mounted volume in the service:

```
volumes:
  - ./dataelasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Here `./dataelasticsearch` basically creates a folder in your local directory which is mounted as a volume. If you want this feature, you do not need the named volume at all.

Comment: This is YAML syntax (not specific to docker). JSON is a subset of YAML, and the `{}` is JSON for an empty set/map. There's no need for compose to document everything you could do with YAML.

Comment: No, it would never ever mean an empty set. `{}` is standard YAML, it indicates a **mapping** (`hashmap`, `dict`, or whatever it is called in your programming language of choice). An empty set would need a tag and  look like `!!set {}`. Leaving it blank gives you the same as doing `dataelasticsearch: null` which is semantically different YAML from `{}`, but of course can be interpreted the same way by docker-compose